# Target class [ProductoController] does not exist. Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, rutas, controller

Muchachos eh creado 2 funciones nuevas en mi controlador de productos, funciones que ya pude en mis rutas, ademas de llamarlas en mi vista principal.... el proceso seria de la siguiente manera; estado en productos.index deseo pasar a la vista productos.aumentar_stock le entrego el parametro "id_pro" para editar la cantidad alli. El problema es que cuando oprimo en mi vista index el boton que me lleva a editar el stock tengo el Error --Target class [ProductoController] does not exist-- Adjunto imagen de mi vista, de mi controlador y de mis rutas. Por favor quisiera que alguien me ayude para avanzar.[`

```js
    public function aumentarStock(Request $request, $id_pro)
    {
        $productos = Producto::findOrFail($id_pro);

        
        $productos->cantidad_pro += $cantidad_pro;
        $productos->save();

        return redirect('productos.show')->back()->with('success', 'Se aumentó el stock del producto.');

    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------

    public function disminuirStock($id_pro, $cantidad_pro)
    {
        $productos = Producto::findOrFail($id_pro);

        // Verificar si hay suficiente stock antes de disminuir
        if ($productos->cantidad_pro >= $cantidad_pro) {
            // Disminuir el stock
            $productos->cantidad_pro -= $cantidad_pro;
            $productos->save();
    
            return redirect('productos.show')->back()->with('success', 'Se disminuyó el stock del producto.');
        } else {
            return redirect('productos.show')->back()->with('error', 'No hay suficiente stock disponible para disminuir.');
        }
    }
```

```css
RUTAS:
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductoController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('/welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::resource('categorias', App\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController::class)->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('marcas', App\Http\Controllers\MarcaController::class)->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('modelos', App\Http\Controllers\ModeloController::class)->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('productos', App\Http\Controllers\ProductoController::class)->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('movimientos', App\Http\Controllers\MovimientoController::class)->middleware('auth');

//Route::get('productos/{productos}/editar',[ProductoController::class, 'aumentarStock'])->name('productos.aumentar_stock');
//Route::get('productos/{producto}/edit2', [ProductoController::class, 'aumentarStock'])->middleware('auth')->name('productos.editstockmas');
//Route::get('productos/{producto}/edit3', [ProductoController::class, 'disminuirStock'])->middleware('auth')->name('productos.editstockmenos');

Route::get('/aumentar-stock/{id_pro}', 'ProductoController@aumentarStock')->name('productos.aumentarStock');
Route::get('/disminuir-stock/{id_pro}', 'ProductoController@disminuirStock')->name('productos.disminuirStock');


Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home')->middleware('auth');
```

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
<title>Productos</title>
@section('template_title')
    Productos
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top:2%">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">

                            <span id="card_title">
                                {{ __('LISTADO DE PRODUCTOS') }}
                            </span>

                            <form action="{{route('productos.index')}}" method="GET" class="col-5" style="margin-top:1%">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="busqueda">
                                    <div class="input-group-append" style="margin-left:1%">
                                        <input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        
                                    
                            <div class="float-right" style="padding-right:5%">
                                <a href="{{ route('productos.create') }}" style="font-size:110%" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right"  data-placement="left">
                                  {{ __('INGRESAR PRODUTO NUEVO') }}
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                            
                                <thead class="thead">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width:3%;">N°</th>
                                        
                                        <th>Id</th>
                                        <th>Nombre de Producto</th>
                                        <th>Stock</th>
                                        <th>Categoria</th>
                                        <th>Marca</th>
                                        
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach ($productos as $paginacion)
                                        <tr>
                                            
                                            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
                                            
                                            <td style="text-align:center">{{ $paginacion->id_pro }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $paginacion->nombre_pro }}</td>
                                            <td style="text-align:center">{{ $paginacion->cantidad_pro }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $paginacion->categoria->nombre_cat }}</td><!-- PUEDE QUE HAYA QUE SOLO QUITAR LA LETRA "S" -->
                                            <td>{{ $paginacion->marca->nombre_mar }}</td>
                                            

                                            <td>
                                                <form action="{{ route('productos.destroy',$paginacion->id_pro) }}" method="POST">
                                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="{{route('productos.show',$paginacion->id_pro) }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i> {{ __('DETALLES') }}</a>    
                                                <a href="{{ route('productos.aumentarStock', ['id_pro' => $paginacion->id_pro]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
                                                    AÑADIR
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="{{ route('productos.disminuirStock', ['id_pro' => $paginacion->id_pro]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                                                    RETIRAR
                                                </a>

                                                @csrf
                                              
                                                </form>
                                            </td>
                                            
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                
                                </tbody>
                            
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {!! $productos->links() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q050e.png)

Comment: Proba poner tus rutas `producto` personalizadas antes de la ruta resource